# django + uwsgi, where to place my startup code?

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I try to place my startup code in `mysite/__init__.py`

When I run `python manage.py run`, the startup code will be executed.

But when I run django with uwsgi, this startup code not executed.

I have tried to put my startup code in several different places, but it gets executed for none of them when uwsgi is started.

What should I do to have the startup code executed when uwsgi starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your startup code in a separate file, for example `startup.py` and then alter these two files:

**manage.py**

```
# some code
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "[project name].settings")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import startup
    # the rest of the code
```

**[project name]/wsgi.py**

```
# some code
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "[project name].settings")
import startup
# the rest of the code
```

Note the order: import is always after `environ` setting (might not be important, depends on what startup does).

In Django1.7 you can use `ready` function per application. Read this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready

Comment: Thanks, the problem is the uwsgi.conf which i used. I set this `module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()`. and use this configure for years. Now, I have follow the django docs, change it to `module=mysite.wsgi:application`, and `import startup` in mysite/wsgi.py.   It's done. same as you.